# Bash - Different Value of parameter Inside If condition

Tags: bash, if-statement

input from file $2 : 1 -> 2

```
while read -a line; do

  if (( ${line[2]} > linesNumber )); then
  echo "Graph does not match known sites4"
    exit
  fi

done < "$2"
```

For some reason inside the `if` condition, the value of `${line[2])` is not `2` 
but if I print the value outside `if`:

```
echo `${line[2]}`

2
```

Comment: Do you mean to have `$linesNumber`

Comment: The value of `${line[2]}` doesn't change `:-)` your mistake is somewhere else!

Comment: I don't think that echo command does what you think it does -- the backquotes mean that it'll take the value of `${line[2]}`, *execute it as a command*, and echo its output.

Answer (score 1):

What's `linesNumber`? Even if you put `$linesNumber`, where is it coming from?

If you are tracking the line number, you need to set it and increment it. Here's my sample program and data. It's *inspired* by your example, but doesn't do exactly what you want. However, it shows you how to setup a variable that tracks the line number, how to increment it, and how to use it in an `if` statement:

#### foo.txt:

```
this 1
that 2
foo  4
barf 4
flux 5
```

#### The Program:

```
lineNum=0
while read -a line
do
    ((lineNum++))
    if (( ${line[1]} > $lineNum ))
    then
        echo "Line Number Too High!"
    fi
    echo "Verb = ${line[0]}  Number = ${line[1]}"
done < foo.txt
```

#### Output:

```
Verb = this  Number = 1
Verb = that  Number = 2
Line Number Too High!
Verb = foo  Number = 4
Verb = barf  Number = 4
Verb = flux  Number = 5
```